# VB6 Running on Windows 8?

Tags: windows, vb6, compatibility, windows-8

Assuming that vb6 does not run on Windows 8 because the VB6 run time libraries are not shipped with Windows 8, would it not be possible to install the VB6 run time library on Windows 8 and then then run VB6? Or is there another problem?

Comment: That may be an excellent question once Windows 8 is out...

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but if you're concerned about compatibility with an operating system that has no exact shipdate yet, then may be you shouldn't use an obsolete technology like VB6. I mean that sincerely.

Comment: When VB6 was first released, its libraries didn't ship with Windows and you have to install them with your app. It's probably safe to assume that future versions of Windows will work with VB6 in the same way.

Comment: The answer may not be the same for ARM and Intel based systems....

Comment: @BeemerGuy - It's not fair to criticize for using VB6. He's probably trying to determine whether he needs to start thinking about rewriting a VB6 app in .NET in anticipation for Windows 8. There are a LOT of VB6 apps out there, and some of them are extensive enough that rewriting them in entirety is extremely prohibitive.

Answer (score 43):

### **EDIT:** Microsoft [is going to support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708) the VB6 runtime in Windows 8.

VB6 apps still work in Windows 8 in the Developer Preview, as of September 13th, 2011).[image: VB6 running in developer preview].  They also run in the Consumer Preview and as stated above, Microsoft are committed to having VB6 just work in Windows 8.

Comment: This was one of the first things I checked when I installed the Developer Preview. I was really surprised, especially given the fairly strong language in the current [support statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms788708), in particular the phrase "there are **no plans to include VB6 runtime in future versions of Windows beyond Windows 7**". I hope Microsoft will clarify this in the near future, hopefully before the RTM is released so that companies trying to figure out exactly what path to take can figure it out before new machines start shipping with Windows 8.

Comment: @MikeSpross Politicians often say they "have no plans to do something": sometimes it means they know it will happen but they don't want to talk about it. Microsoft said something very similar before Windows 7. Microsoft also have a vested interest in encouraging people to migrate by making scary statements. They also have lots of big customers with millions of lines of VB6 and no decent migration route.

Comment: @Mike Microsoft have now announced the VB6 [runtime is supported on Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nb-no/vbrun/ms788708%28en-us%29.aspx). I have edited this into Kris's answer, hope that's OK Kris. No disrespect but... **I told you so** :) And now we wait for the statement that "there are no plans to support VB6 in Windows 9"

Comment: @MarkJ Hehe. Honestly, once it was in the Developer Preview, I couldn't imagine them taking it out later in the RTM. But, good news, and I agree VB6 probably isn't going anywhere anytime soon.

Answer (score 23):

This is a very difficult question to truly answer, but I'll try and provide the best response that I can.

**We really don't know for sure**, seeing as how it has not been released yet and is probably only in the early stages of development. There is also no way to predict what kind of hacks might surface to allow VB6 applications to run on Windows 8. I have a fair bit of confidence that it will be only a matter of time before the community comes up with some sort of workaround, if you're really all that concerned. I will probably even look into it myself, if for no other reason than pure curiosity.

**However, the [official word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nb-no/vbrun/ms788708(en-us).aspx) is that this configuration will likely not be supported:**

> ...there are no plans to include VB6 runtime in future versions of Windows beyond Windows 7.

It's also worth considering the talk about Windows 8 being released only in a 64-bit version (as is the case with Server 2008 R2). Since the VB6 runtime (and all applications created by the VB6 compiler) are 32-bit, they will have to run in an emulated 32-bit layer (WOW). Some apps have already experienced issues running in 64-bit versions of Windows 7, and this problem may only get worse. The IDE is currently [not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nb-no/vbrun/ms788708(en-us).aspx) on 64-bit versions of Windows, making continued maintenance of legacy applications only that much more difficult (although for what it's worth, I just installed it on my dev box running Server 2008 R2 without any problems).

Comment: A good answer. But I think Microsoft's statement is very carefully worded. Politicians often say they "have no plans to do something":  sometimes it means they know it will happen but they don't want to talk about it. Microsoft may support VB6 in Windows 8, or they may not. They have a vested interest in encouraging people to migrate by being cagey. They also have lots of big customers with millions of lines of VB6 and no decent migration route. They only announced that the VB6 runtime would be in Windows 7 a few months before the release.

Comment: I think **include** is the key word, the VB6 runtime may still be able to be installed by hand.

Comment: That quote was also used with Windows Vista.

Comment: Microsoft have now announced the VB6 [runtime is supported on Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nb-no/vbrun/ms788708%28en-us%29.aspx). No disrespect but... **I told you so** :) And now we wait for the statement that "there are no plans to support it in Windows 9"

Comment: Yes, indeed. I noticed this a long time ago. I should be motivated to update this answer for accuracy, given all of the residual upvotes it manages to bring in, but I'm really not.

Answer (score 17):

Microsoft updated their support statement as of January 2012.  It appears VB6 will be supported in Windows 8.

> VB6 runtime will ship and will be supported in Windows 8 for the lifetime of the OS. Visual Basic 6.0 runtime files continue to be 32-bit only and all components must be hosted in 32-bit application processes. Developers can think of the support story for Windows 8 being the same as it is for Windows 7.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708

Answer (score 3):

> Microsoft last month announced that it was extending “It Just Works”
>   compatibility for Visual Basic 6 applications for the full lifetime of
>   Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, Windows 7 and (most importantly)
>   Windows 8. As described on the Visual Basic 6.0 Resource Center, “the
>   core Visual Basic 6.0 runtime will be supported for the full lifetime”
>   of these operating systems. The commitment comprises five years of
>   mainstream support followed by five years of extended support.
>
> Karl Peterson is a VB6 programmer and formerly a longtime columnist at
>   Visual Studio Magazine and Visual Basic Programming Journal (where he
>   wrote the popular VB Corner column, among others, until 2010).
>   Peterson notes that this announcement officially puts the lifetime of
>   the VB6 runtime past his projected retirement. And that fact may have
>   implications for enterprises sitting on large amounts of working VB6
>   code, which Peterson calls “the COBOL of the 2020s.”
>
> “Many in the Classic VB community started out back in the pre-Windows
>   days, and are now at the point of seeing retirement on the horizon,”
>   he says. “And the loss of that institutional knowledge at many
>   enterprises will only further entrench the functional code base.”
>
> Peterson says Microsoft’s decision reflects the fact that VB6 adoption
>   went beyond the “hobbyist or shareware type author who was the
>   guerilla in the enterprise.” He says Microsoft was likely moved to
>   extend support because businesses still maintain VB6 code of real
>   value, and are in no position to immediately migrate off it.

Source: [MSDN Magazine](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnmagazine/archive/2012/02/13/10267361.aspx)

http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifepolicy

Answer (score 3):

It does work on windows 8 and 8.1 and even on windows 10

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has everything to gain and nothing to lose by insuring backwards compatibility. Visual Studio advertised Interop as a way to integrate Vb6 technology with .net; seems like Microsoft would be shooting itself in the foot if it removed this compatibility as I presume vb6 runtimes are required for Interop to work.

Comment: I wouldn't say that they don't have anything to lose.  Backwards compatibility testing, documentation of features etc, all cost money during a development cycle.

Comment: And really, what would they stand to gain by supporting an ancient development technology, apart from a bit of good will?

Answer (score 2):

I think all ActiveX libraries will still working the same way they actually do under Windows 7. Remember Microsoft says Windows 8 will have a ''classic Windows mode'' (with desktop, menu bar, etc like Windows 7).

Other question is about ARM systems, I think there will be two scenarios: x86 programs will not work at all, or Microsoft will include an emulation layer for use Intel programs (at performance cost).

So Windows 8 will probably not be the deadline for VB6 and all the related software, but problems will increase for sure until the day we can't use in any way. So be prepared for virtualize and run VB6 with software like XP Mode (Virtual PC), VirtualBox, VMWare, etc.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell they work just the same in Windows 8 as they do in Windows 7 - they've said that everything in Windows 7 will work in Windows 8 (assuming hardware is the same). There are still a huge number of VB6 apps out there so it makes no sense for them to drop support for no reason. You could get some guys from the [Windows 8 forums](http://www.win8forums.com) to check it out, as they will have access to builds other than the Developer Preview and may be able to get some feedback for you.

There's also a post here which may help you: [Google Groups Post](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.vb.general.discussion/browse_thread/thread/c36c22f5489e935f)

Answer (score 2):

Visual Basic 6 works on Windows 8 , 8.1 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I've read that the you can place the msvbvm60.dll in the same folder as your Visual Basic 6 exe and it works.    I have not personally verified this and not, of course, in Windows 8.

I have an utility I'm selling with 20K lines of VB6 code which only requires a drag and drop deployment with no install package.  So I have an intense interest in this problem in Windows 8 as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to install the VB6 IDE on the 32-bit Windows 8 Preview build and compile some existing apps. I haven't yet had success in installing on the 64-bit version.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen, the VB6 runtime does seem to work...but my attempts at installing the IDE on Windows 8 RTM 64-bit was a colossal failure.  I ran into lots of very major errors (seems like a number had to do with OLE registration) and the installer didn't even finish properly.  I'll stick with my XP VM for VB6 development.

I'd also approach cautiously with regard to what does *work* in Windows 8.  Just being able to load and show a plain vanilla form is far different from running an ADO connection to a SQL Server, loading and playing media, or doing any type of serious socket communication.  As always, test thoroughly!  :)

Edit: Looks like Microsoft's support statement (linked to in another comment) validates that Windows 8 as it stands will not support the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I have a large VB6 app running on both windows 7 and windows 10 for a while. Took some tweaking to get it working but no issues at all.

Comment: This question is a decade old, and was asked before the official release of Windows 8. As the top answer suggests, Microsoft subsequently announced support for this configuration. Your answer confirms what is already established by the existing answers, but doesn’t add anything new. If you could edit your answer to include e.g., the tweaking you needed to perform to ensure this worked, that might be useful. But otherwise, just upvote one of the existing answers confirming compatibility instead of reiterating what’s already been said as a new answer.

Comment: Also, the question is not about either Windows 7 or Windows 10, but is specific to Windows 8. (Though, one might imagine, support under both suggests support in intermediate releases.)