# vbscript Compatibility Issues with windows 8

Tags: vb6, vbscript, asp-classic, compatibility, windows-8

My company is currently hosting a legacy application that contains a great deal of vbscript (client side browser and task automation ), classic asp and some vb 6. (I know pretty old) While we are in the works of rewriting a lot of it piecemeal. We will eventually need to support windows-8. Is there a list of issues or compatibility tips to look at in supporting windows 8?

### Update

#### [VB6 Running on Windows 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221661/vb6-running-on-windows-8) partially answers mine as far as VB 6. But still concerned about vbscript.

#### [vbscript support in windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/software/2048-vbscript-support.html) covers a good deal more

Comment: do You mean 2008 or Windows 7?

Comment: I mean windows 8 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8

Comment: There is still a lot of speculation out there. It's probably a good idea to wait for one of the beta, RC, or RTM version to become available (MS have given access to time limited VMs for testing on the last few releases)

Comment: The [developer preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516) is now available to download.

Comment: Downloading now... this will be my weekend at least. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything that runs on Windows 7 should run on Windows 8 in desktop mode.  None of the technologies you list will work in the new Metro style applications.

Comment: Since Metro is rendered using IE's Trident engine (from recent remarks) I suspect that a whole lot of those technologies will work.  Only time will tell, we don't have the SDK or much else but a preview OS and some pre-release VS tools.

Comment: @Bob, the SDK comes on the pre-release iso.

Comment: Must be included in the giant download with all of the VS bits people don't necessarily need.  Good point though.

Answer (score 0):

AS long as you have the VB6 runtime DLL it should be backwards compatible.

IIS7 and 7.5 both support Classic ASP pages, so you shouldn't have any problems.  In the near future, you want to get those migrated to .NET.

Comment: does that include the windows scripting host?

Comment: I'm in the process of migration now. However given the current circumstances we may not be able to rewrite all of our 10 year old legacy code in time to support the newest version. Based on what is still functional we can better prioritize what will be done first in the rewrite.

Comment: It should be compatible. wsh scripts run just fine in 2008 and so do vbs files all the same. You really should migrate over the next few years though. WIth the ever changing architecture and landscape of things, you should migrate those wsh scripts to cmdlets wish powershell. Powershell will be around of years to come.

Comment: not talking about windows server 2008 and yes I am aware, we "should". Again we are in the process of migrating things over to .NET. Just need to know how to prioritize.

Comment: (Google windows 8) Believe me, I am well aware of the need to migrate.

Comment: Just loaded the 8 developer preview. All my vbs works fine and so do .NET apps. The VB6 programs work out of the box as well, You should be fine.

Comment: Thank you much. Still updating everything but that definitely helps.

Comment: Interface in 8 is pretty slick. I was not aware of its existence until now! I usually get alerted in MSDN and my technet accounts.

Comment: VBScript is unrelated to VB6 and does not use its runtime.